# How to recursively search the DOM and return first element that has a specified class

Tags: dom, recursion

For example - return the 1st element that has class = "title". 
The result in this case should be *div3.1*
Should only use vanilla JS.

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="abc"> div1</div>
            <div class="abc"> div2
                <div class="abc">div2.1
                    <a href="http://"></a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, ipsum?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="abc">div2.2</div>
                <div class="abc">div2.3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="abc"> div3
                <div class="title">div3.1</div>
                <div class="title">div3.2
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: `var abc = document.querySelector('.abc')`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about recursively, but `querySelector()` does just that. It will find the first element that matches the given parameter. The parameter is a CSS selector, so:

id: `#abc`

class: `.abc`

attribute: `[abc]`

tag: `div`

There's the old school way as well using `getElementsByClassName()`:

```
var abc = document.getElementsByClassName('abc')[0];
```

The `getElementsByClassName()` returns a **HTMLCollection/NodeList** of all elements with a given className, using the bracket notation (`[0]`) suffix insures that it only returns the first element of the NodeList.

### Demo

```js
var title1 = document.querySelector('.title');
var title2 = document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0];

console.log(title1.textContent);
console.log(title2.textContent);
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="abc"> div1</div>
            <div class="abc"> div2
                <div class="abc">div2.1
                    <a href="http://"></a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, ipsum?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="abc">div2.2</div>
                <div class="abc">div2.3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="abc"> div3
                <div class="title">div3.1</div>
                <div class="title">div3.2
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you provided too little details in your question. If you want to find element with specified class, you can use `document.querySelector` method.

You can't "recursively" search whole DOM (starting from certain node I'm assuming?), but you can search specific DOM "branch" (element and its parents, up to document body). You can use function like:

```
function findElementWithClass(sourceElement, className){
    var element = sourceElement; //selected DOM node

    while(element !== document.body){
        if(element.classList.contains(className)){
            break;
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    return element;
}
```

After while loop you can make additional check if element you wanted has been found - if not, you can return false or do whatever you like.

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/8o9jzt8h/